# Router's page shows “Index of /”

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I need to configure my pre-installed router (redirect ports, etc.), but when I visit it's http://192.168.1.1 page, it returns

```
Index of /
1. ../
modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:08 GMT
directory - 0.00 kbyte
```

page.

Is there a way I can configure my router without resetting it?

P.S. Links

```
http://192.168.1.1/basic.htm
http://192.168.1.1/StaRouter.htm
http://192.168.1.1/Filters.htm
```

return **Not Found. The requested URL /basic.htm was not found on this server.**.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer your question.  Have you by chance in the past disable the web configuration capabilties of the router?

Comment: @Ramhound router was configured by ISP.

Comment: Need the make/model of the router

Comment: You should get your own router. ISP supplied routers are terrible anyways.

Comment: It sounds like your router is actually your modem, which is typically called a gateway not a router.

Comment: @AndroidDev - Not all countries/ISPs allow replacing your ISP modem/router. You cannot generalise on that.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I made no mention of replacing the modem. I see no reason why (or even how) an ISP could block you from using your own router. You unplug their router from the modem, and plug in yours. The modem doesn't care what it's connected to.

Comment: They're usually a single box these days, in the UK anyway. You cannot replace it because it needs an auth code, which you can only get by a tech ringing his tech line. This has been the case in the UK since the dawn of ADSL & continues into cable. You can dumb the router down to pure modem, then put a router behind, but the market for those is still tiny over here.

Comment: @Ramhound I have [TP-Link Router](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/TL-WR841N.html). It was working badly at times, so ISP techs came and reflashed it. It works fine now but I cannot access it to apply ports forwarding rules. Not sure yet if I miss something simple or I should just unsubscribe from ISP.

Comment: Why would your ISP flash your personal router?  Are you sure what they didn't flash wasn't some other device which was there equipment ( i.e. your actual modem).  Why are you against resetting the device, based on the behavior, it sounds like the default configuration of the binary they used ( if they flashed that device ) is configured to disable the web configuration.

Comment: Verify the address the router is being assigned is actually the ip address you are attempting to access, my guess, your router is assigned an entirely different ip address and your actually tring to access a different network device more then likely your modem.

Comment: @Ramhound router is ISP's device: they provided it. Originally (first year of service) router had original configuration (as resetting will bring it to now, I suppose), but last months router started to work badly (as I was told by support, it's something in conjuction of router and their server), so they came to "find the problem", but actually just reflashed it. If I will reset it, so problem may still arise and I won't be able to put the responsibility on ISP again.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows' **ipconfig** command shows gateway as 192.168.1.1 only, what I'm trying to access. Not sure if I have any other device I'm able to connect to (which responds with "Index of /" page). Problematic router I have is just servers to redirect packets to PC / Wi-Fi / TVs.

Comment: The device isn't configured correctly.  Contact your ISP if your not willng to reset the device or flash the device yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound got it. Could you please copy-paste the same as an actual answer so I could accept it?